# How can i add a new line for every value in a field using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys basically I'm using pandas to create a data framework  but I would like to order the values with a new line in a cerntain field

```
result_df = df.groupby('Date (Spent)').agg({'User': 'first','Work package': lambda x:'\n'.join(x), 'Units': lambda x: x.sum() + 1}).reset_index()
```

I'm trying the following approach with '/n' but I'm not getting what i need

the row shoud look something like this:

```
  date     Work package
26/12/23     "apple"
             "onion"
             "orange"
```

is there a way i can achieve this?